# PHP Excel Reader (excel_reader2.php)

Tags: php, excel

Is it possible to search a certain value inside the spreadsheet using excel_reader2 and get row number so I can get the entire row value using that? Trying to save myself from dumping the data into database, since all I want is to displaying values. 
And yes I know I can do data->dump, but I need a single row values based on login.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: used foreach($data->sheets[0]['cells'] as $row) instead of for($i=0; i<=rowcount($sheet_index=0); i++) to go through all the rows and time improved amazingly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls",false);
$data->val($row,$col,$sheet_index)                     //$data->val(10,A);
```

You can go through all rows and cols with foreach loop and find a "column and row" with word using regexp function.

Comment: Great. Problem is going with a for loop takes too long. I was wondering if there might be a "find" type of utility. Or a different way that does not take so  long.

Comment: longer than 2 minutes for 800 records!

Comment: Try to use flag "false" for large worksheets to not storing the extended information about cells like fonts, colors.